Multiple retry configurations for Resilience4J in Spring Boot?
How can I configure different Resilience4J retry behaviours for different exceptions  using Spring Boot?
I have a service that relies on Resilience4J for improved resilience:
@Service
class SomeService {

    @RateLimiter(name = "rateLimiter")
    @Retry(name = "retryTwice", fallbackMethod = "fallback")
    void doSomethingImportant(int id) {
        // do something important
    }

    void fallback(int id, Throwable throwable) {
        // fallback logic
    }
}

with the following Spring Boot / Resilience4J configuration:
resilience4j.retry:
  instances:
    retryTwice:
      maxAttempts: 2
      retryExceptions:
        - org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException # remote server problem
        - io.github.resilience4j.ratelimiter.RequestNotPermitted  # rate limit exceeded


resilience4j.ratelimiter:
  limiters:
    rateLimiter:
      limitForPeriod: 1
      limitRefreshPeriod: 1s
      timeoutDuration: 3s

In an attempt to increase the number of retry attempts in case the rate limit is exceeded, I tried to add a second @Retry annotation to the method:
@Service
class SomeService {

    /*
     * Second '@Retry' annotation added, does not compile
     */
    @RateLimiter(name = "rateLimiter")
    @Retry(name = "retryTwice", fallbackMethod = "fallback")
    @Retry(name = "retryTenTimes", fallbackMethod = "fallback")
    void doSomethingImportant(int id) {
        // do something important
    }

    void fallback(int id, Throwable throwable) {
        // fallback logic
    }
}

and update the configuration accordingly:
resilience4j.retry:
  instances:
    retryTwice:
      maxAttempts: 2
      retryExceptions:
        - org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException # remote server problem
    retryTenTimes:
      maxAttempts: 10
      retryExceptions:
        - io.github.resilience4j.ratelimiter.RequestNotPermitted  # rate limit exceeded

resilience4j.ratelimiter:
  limiters:
    rateLimiter:
      limitForPeriod: 1
      limitRefreshPeriod: 1s
      timeoutDuration: 3s

The problem is that this code does not compile (because @Retry is not a @Repeatable annotation). Is there an idiomatic way of solving this problem? If not, how can I work around it?
